# Alguem sabe dizer porquê no meu console não aparece resultado de nada?

Tags: java, lista-encadeada

Receber um valor `n` e imprimir a tabela a seguir, utilizando o encadeamento da estrutura `for`:

```
1
2   4
3   9  27
4  16  64  256
n  n²  n³  ...  n^n
```

Tentei:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Questao4 {

    public void Cadeia() {
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Informe um número: ");
        int n = num.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {

                System.out.println(Math.pow(i,j) + "");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Postei uma resposta com variável, com base na sua pergunta original. Nada impede de eliminar o `r` e deixar o `Math.pow` dentro do print

Comment: Muito obrigado por ajudar tbm! :)

Comment: @EmersonAraujo seja bem vindo, que bom que a resposta te ajudou  com sua dúvida / problema, aproveite e faça o [tour] para saber como funciona a **comunidade**.

Comment: Que bom que foi util, o importante é que com o edit, você esclareceu coisas que não daria com o post original. Quando puder, dê uma lida em [help] e [ask], e procure sempre elaborar a pergunta com os detalhes relevantes, assim agiliza a chance de resposta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz algumas correções e ajustes, e listei para você entender os efeitos de cada mudança:

- Trocada condição `i < n` por `i <= n` para que o número de linhas corresponda ao digitado;
- Trocada condição `j < n` por `j <= i`, para atender ao enunciado;
- criada uma variavel `r` para armazenar o resultado do `pow`, que é um `double`;
- adicionada a variável `r` no print com base na [versão 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/324305/1) da pergunta, com cálculo em separado;
- trocado o `println` por `print` no *loop*, para não pular linha entre os valores;
- remoção do `""` dentro do `println` final, é desnecessário se só quer a quebra de linha.

```
class Questao4 {
    public void Cadeia() {
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Informe um número: ");
        System.out.println();

        int n = num.nextInt();
        double r;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                r = Math.pow(i,j);
                System.out.print(r + "        ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/JIfnnr)**

Comment: Muito obrigado. Foi muito esclarecedor. Obrigado msm
Tava errando em fazer os dois "for" em função de "n".